# Quartz crystal gasket, isolator, platform or whatever

Tags: crystal

Spent enormous time looking for these parts, and can not even find how they are called. Tried mouser, digikey, farnell, arrow. The best I found is "crystal insulator (thermal)" which is not what I am looking for.

By the way, last time I obtained them by desoldering old SMD quartz crystal assemblies.

[image]

Edit: yes, I want my THT crystal mounted to look this way, being held by this assembly

[image]

Why obsolete?

Comment: A description what they are supposed to do would help. Is this to insulate a HC49 -ish crystal from the PCB?

Comment: If BIVAR doesn't make it , it's obsolete. Even wood will do. It's Just a strain relief from damage to internal gold wirebond.

Answer (score 1):

It seems they changed the design so it looks different, but everyone still stocks the BIVAR parts.

https://www.digikey.com/products/en/crystals-oscillators-resonators/accessories/175?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv1989=0&sf=0&FV=-8|175%2Cii2|2245&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25

Comment: These are ugly ersatz :( I have several of these, but decided to disassemble SMD crystals because their plastic basements are far more elegant and easier to use.